# rails rspec model validation with with_options statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I use rspec to test my model. I have `with_options` statements in my model validations. How can I handle it in my tests?

```
with_options({on: :some}) do |s|
 s.validates :name, presence: true
end

with_options({on: :some2}) do |s2|
 s2.validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: thos `with_options` are just a DRY, but you can still test the model validations. That `with_options` shouldn't be matter. Can you show the test code you wrote for this?

Comment: it is like this :`  it "is valid with valid name" do
    @address.should be_valid
  end
  it "is not valid without a name" do
    @address.name = nil
    @address.should_not be_valid
  end`

Comment: The generic answer is "You write a test that ensures what you want to have happen is actually happening, and what you don't want doesn't happen."  A more specific answer would be for this sort of thing I usually go with the shoulda matchers gem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to test a model that has `with_options` validations:

```
@myinstance.should_not be_valid(:some)
```